# Showing pagination links based on total number of records

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate, kaminari

So i am using rails and want to proceed with either `will_paginate or kaminari` for pagination. Here is my below requirement.

- I have lets say 900 records and want to show 10 records per page. So in total i want to show 90 links in pagination like >. So just based on records count i want to perform this.

So my question is, Though i have overall 900 records, my end point only gives me 10 records at the start. But I want to show links for 900 records (10 records per page). Using pagination later i want to load dynamically whenever user has clicked random page.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: I think you got to look at this first https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#helpers

Comment: @Ojash tell me what you got

Comment: you could define the `window` to control how many pages link you want to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I go with Ojash answer. you can use kaminari and specify the window.

```
<%= paginate @users, :outer_window => 3 %>
```